# How to structure React smart and dumb components with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have three components to handle *Adding/Deleting Hashtags*. Let it be three files like

- HashTags.ts *- smart component*
- ShowHashTags.ts *- dumb component*
- AddHashTags.ts *- smart? component*

HashTags component fetches data from server and handle two other events: Adding new *hashtag* and Deleting *hashtag*.

AddHashTags component is handling *Adding action* (pushing on server) and then fires *onUpdate* function to tell it's master component to update data (from server).

ShowHashTags component displays data and also handles onDelete action.

Let me show you code of **HashTags** component:

```
const HashTags: React.FC = () => {
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]); // rows - is data to display (rows of table)
    const [update, setUpdate] = useState(Symbol()); // check the way I fire Update event

    useEffect(() => {
        loadHashTag().then(hashtags => {
            setRows(hashtags);
        });
    }, [update]); // fires "onInit" and when I force to change "update"

    const deleteTag = (id) => {
        deleteHashTag(id).then(() => {
            setUpdate(Symbol()); // force update
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <AddHashTags onUpdate={() => setUpdate(Symbol())} />
            <ShowHashTags data={rows} onDelete={deleteTag} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

Please notice how I force update action. How good is it? I just need to set new random value to "update" field to fire hook useEffect.

So my question is what is the best mechanism to make such a thing? My code works but I'm just wondering how good is it.

P.S. it's okay for me to fetch data from server twice. I could use global store or push back updated data from AddHashTags component, but it's okay for me to fetch data one more time (even to be sure data is added).